# After adding critical section controller, the number of aggregate report samples is incorrect

Tags: jmeter

When number of threads (users): is set below 10, the number of samples is displayed correctly. When number of threads (users): is set to 10, the number of samples is 18 ~ 20.The expected result should be 22. Please point out the problem for me.

JMeter version: 5.4.3
The script settings are as follows:

```
-- Thread Group

 -- Thread Properties
    Number of Threads （users）：11
    Ramp-up period （seconds）：2
    Loop Count:Infinite 2

 -- Critical Section Controller
      --HTTP Request 1
      --HTTP Request 2
      --HTTP Request 3
      --HTTP Request 4
      --HTTP Request 5

 -- Aggregate Report  # Samples
      --HTTP Request     20
      --HTTP Request     20
      --HTTP Request     19
      --HTTP Request     18
      --HTTP Request     18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

and I can think of the following reasons:

1. You have artificial limitation of the test execution time in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   [image]
2. You have responses filtering configured in the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener, i.e. if this box is ticked - you will see only requests which were successful and failed ones won't be displayed:

   [image]

   Try [re-running your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) and see how many results are in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)
3. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

---

And last but not the least, do you realize the concept of the Critical Section Controller? In your setup it means "no concurrency", all HTTP Request samplers will be executed by one thread at a time only so the equivalent setup would be

[image]

Comment: As you said, I do tick Specify Thread lifetime, if I don't tick the problem goes away.I benefited a lot from your answer. Thank you for answering my question.